# Can you help me about in gradle error Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-workmanager

can you help me about this error in Android studio.

I am using the new WorkManager library version  and i have the following error in Android studio, an you help me?

```
 org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task
 ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.   at
 org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
    at
 org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
    at
  ...
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
 java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException:
 com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge
 dex . . . Caused by: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files
 define Lcom/google/common/util/concurrent/ListenableFuture;
```

Comment: please add your **build.gradle'(Module: app)** setting

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your app level build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3' // ADD THIS LINE
  // rest of your dependencies
}
```

and this in your defaultConfig:

```
defaultConfig {
    ...
    minSdkVersion 15 
    targetSdkVersion 26
    multiDexEnabled true // ADD THIS LINE
}
```

You can read more about this here: [Enable Multidex for apps with more than 64k methods](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex)

Comment: can you post your gradle file